# In WiX, where is the ProductCode specified?

Tags: wix

I'm using WiX to create an installer, and in order to uninstall my application from the command line (using `MsiExec.exe /X{...}`) I need to know the ProductCode for my .msi file.

When I install my application, I can see that the `ProductCode` is listed in the installation log file. However, the GUID shown does not feature anywhere in my WiX files. It also seems to change between builds of my installer.

Can I specify the `ProductCode` somewhere in my WiX `.wsx` file? If so, where?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The product code is the Id of the Product element.

Specifying a guid

```
<Product Id="INSERT_GUID_HERE"
```

Specifying a '*' makes the GUID auto generate every time

```
<Product Id="*"
```

Or you can store the product code as a variable in a config.wxi file and reference it like so

```
<Product Id="$(var.MyProductCode)"
```

Comment: In addition to this answer, I found that `MsiExec.exe /X{...}` requires the Guid to be the Win32_Product `IdentifyingNumber` (as opposed to the Win32_Product `PackageCode`). Note: It is NEVER safe to query `Win32_Product`, so never do it on a production box.