# Major upgrade on a multi-instance installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer, multi-instance-deployment

I'm reluctant to ask this question at this time, as I repeat [WiX - Doing a major upgrade on a multi instance install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860622/wix-doing-a-major-upgrade-on-a-multi-instance-install/22862283)... Yet I hope my question will get answered :)

I have an installer with multiple instances:

```
<Product Id="{GUID}" UpgradeCode="{GUID}" Version="!(wix.Version)" Name="MyProduct" Manufacturer="MyCompany">

  <MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallExecute" DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />

  <Property Id="INSTANCEID" Value="Default" />
  <InstanceTransforms Property="INSTANCEID">
    <Instance Id="I01" ProductName="MyProduct_I01" ProductCode="{GUID}" UpgradeCode="{GUID}" />
    <Instance Id="I02" ProductName="MyProduct_I02" ProductCode="{GUID}" UpgradeCode="{GUID}" />
    .
    .
    .
    <Instance Id="I49" ProductName="MyProduct_I49" ProductCode="{GUID}" UpgradeCode="{GUID}" />
    <Instance Id="I50" ProductName="MyProduct_I50" ProductCode="{GUID}" UpgradeCode="{GUID}" />
  </InstanceTransforms>
</Product>
```

For the sake of clarity, every new version uses:

- A different version number (different in at least one of the first 3 numbers)
- A different product code for each instance
- The same upgrade code for each instance
- I install each product with domain admin privileges

Before changing the product code every new release I used the same one for each version, and though it was a bit clumsy (retaining deleted components forever), the re-install process worked out.

Now, however, subsequent re-installations using different versions make msiexec.exe see all the components as missing, thus failing the installation. It looked as if it was time to transition to major upgrades!

**Upgrading the naïve way**

`msiexec.exe /i "installer.msi" /n {OLD_VERSION_PRODUCTCODE}`

Prompted a false message:

> The system administrator has set policies to prevent this installation.

**Upgrade via re-install**

`msiexec.exe /i "installer.msi" /n {OLD_VERSION_PRODUCTCODE} REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vamus`

(also tried with `REINSTALLMODE=amus` since a new product is a new install, but nope)

Logged each component as absent and didn't touch any file (the upgrade was reported successful):

> Installed: Absent;   Request: Null;   Action: Null

I'm at a loss -- what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an awkward solution, but it's only fit for an awkward problem:

```
<SetProperty Id="REINSTALL" Value="" Before="AppSearch" />
<SetProperty Id="REINSTALLMODE" Value="" Before="AppSearch" />
```

By unsetting the `REINSTALL` properties I somehow skip over the major upgrade permission hurdle and avert a real re-installation, leaving me with the new version.

I will happily accept a more orthodox solution, specifically one that doesn't involve fiddling with Windows Installer properties...